# Adding the collision object "wall" to moveit-rviz

Tags: ros, moveit, collision-object

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was trying to add a wall to my robot its planning scene by creating a node that will spawn this wall. With these walls I want to set the workspace.

When I run it I don't get any errors but nothing really happens either.

This is the code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h"
#include "moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h"
#include "geometric_shapes/shape_operations.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "building_workspace");
    ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
    spinner.start();

    const std::string PLANNING_GROUP = "manipulator";
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group(PLANNING_GROUP);

    moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;
    Eigen::Vector3d b(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);

    moveit_msgs::CollisionObject collision_object;
    collision_object.id = "wall";
    shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/box1.stl", b);
    ROS_INFO("wall mesh loaded");

    shape_msgs::Mesh mesh;
    shapes::ShapeMsg mesh_msg;
    shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m, mesh_msg);
    mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(mesh_msg);

    collision_object.meshes.resize(1);
    collision_object.mesh_poses.resize(1);
    collision_object.meshes[0] = mesh;
    collision_object.header.frame_id = move_group.getPlanningFrame();
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].position.x = -0.5;
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].position.y = -0.5;
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].position.z = -0.1;
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x = 1.57;

    collision_object.meshes.push_back(mesh);
    collision_object.mesh_poses.push_back(collision_object.mesh_poses[0]);
    collision_object.operation = collision_object.ADD;
    std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_vector;
    collision_vector.push_back(collision_object);

    planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_vector);
    ROS_INFO("Wall added into the world");
    move_group.attachObject(collision_object.id);
    sleep(5.0);
    ros::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Would be nice if somebody could help me out!

Kind regards,
Edwin van Emmerik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273731/adding-the-collision-object-%22wall%22-to-moveit-rviz/) by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You definitely do not want to attach your wall to your planning group in the end. Attaching only makes sense for objects the robot grasped.

Use `planning_scene_interface.applyCollisionObject` instead of `addCollisionObject` unless you know what you are doing.
This should spawn your object successfully.
We should really rework the tutorial here and advertise `apply*` as the default option...

Notice that if your workspace is *static* throughout runtime, the more simple way to add walls is to model them *as part of the robot* in your urdf/xacro instead. In that case they also remain there after someone clears the planning scene.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on 2017-10-21**:
Thank you very much! I do want to keep my workspace able to change for now though. Should I add it to the google group with a link to this question?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-21**:
You're welcome. No need to add a link to the mailing list.
Software usage questions don't belong there in the first place.